# Tinymce Editor: content not update when click another button in Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="example.com" id="form">
  <textarea id="content">{{$content_from_database}}</textarea>
  <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

I use `tinymce editor` inside the form:

```
 tinymce.init({ 
    selector:'textarea#content'
 });
```

Once i click the submit button after the content is updated:

```
$('textarea#content').val() = 'old content'
```

Content still is the old content.

**UPDATED**

Ajax code:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function() {
  $.post(
   $(this).prop('action'), {
     "content": $('textarea[name=content]').val(),
   },
   function(d){
     console.log(d);
   },
   'text'
   ).done(function() {
     alert('successful');
   }).fail(function(e) {
     alert('failed');
   });
   return false;
});
```

How can I fix this?

Please help me!

Thank you very much!

Comment: How are you submitting the form?  AJAX?  Normal form submit?  Without seeing more code around how you are submitting the form people will just be guessing how to help you fix this issue.

Comment: Hi @MichaelFromin, I was updated question

Comment: Please see my answer below...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using AJAX to submit the form you need to use the `tinyMCE.triggerSave()` API call to get TinyMCE to update the underlying `<textarea>`.

When you load TinyMCE your original `<textarea>` is actually "hidden" by an iFrame and other DOM elements that TinyMCE loads into the page.  As you are typing into TinyMCE the editor does not continually keep the `<textarea>` in sync.

Calling `tinyMCE.triggerSave()` will force the editor to update the underlying `<textarea>` and then you can use AJAX to submit the form that contains the `<textarea>`.

I suspect that you will need to add it before this portion of your code as this appears to expect the `<textarea>` to have correct content.

```
$(this).prop('action'), {
    "content": $('textarea[name=content]').val(),
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but I have some code and it working good: `tinymce.init({ 
  selector:'#content',
  setup: function(editor){
   editor.on('GetContent', function(e) {       
       $('#content').val(e.content);
   })}});`

Comment: Thanks so much :)